# Move mail from specific address to an inbox folder

Tags: email, imap, gmail-imap

Is there a way I can set up my mail to automatically move to a specific inbox folder depending on the source address?

EDIT:

I'm using thunderbird specifically. Mac, Windows, and Linux. from address: "someoneIknow@gmail.com" and I want to move their messages to my inbox folder "someoneIknow".

Comment: `gear - settings - filters tab - create filter new filter` and use the `from` field and `create filter with this search` where it applies an inbox label. This is for the web version; are you using a client?

Comment: unless you want to hear "of course there is a way" describe your enviromnment. What software are you using? What should happen? When?

Comment: I added more information

Comment: @Raystafarian: If you make this an answer I can upvote it and mark as the right answer.

Comment: @kisplit Made an answer, but that's for the web version, are you looking to filter it via labels in the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gear - settings - filters tab - create filter new filter` and use the from field and create filter with this search where it applies an inbox label. This is for the web version; are you using a client?

Comment: I setup my filters following your instructions and it produces same results on thunderbird. Thanks!